# Vuetify 1.5 v-select don't close with closeOnClick

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the v-select component and I need to use the event to close it by clicking (closeOnClick), but for some reason it doesn't work.

I am using **:menu-props**, but I do not get the expected result

I am using Vuetify version 1.5.

I leave my code.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="wt-text-div" :class="{ 'wt-text-div-active': textClass}" v-if="label">
            <label class="wt-text-div-label">{{ label }}</label>
        </div>
        <v-select
            @blur="eventBlur"
            @focus="setClass"
            :label="label_item"
            solo
            :class="[
                size == 'size-m' ? 'wt-field-size-m' : 'wt-field-size-s',
                {'wt-field-margin-10': hide_details},
            ]"
            :disabled=disabled
            :rules="rules"
            :value="value"
            :menu-props="{
                'bottom': true,
                'offsetY': true,
            }"
            :items="options"
            :append-icon="'$vuetify.icons.arrowClose'"
            :hide-details=hide_details
        >
        </v-select>
    </div>
</template>
```